# Xcode bug? Cannot make UITableViewCell with "detail right" style in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Please see the attached pictures. When I make a UITableViewCell in a storyboard and I select "detail right" as the cell's style, the label and text label are not visible.

I found that this is because Xcode is setting their font sizes to 0!  While I can increase the size, I cannot change the labels' frames, which are also set to strangely small values, and so the text is truncated.

This problem does not appear with the other cell styles. The Xcode version is 5.0.2.

What is wrong here and how to I fix it?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has resolved itself. The cause remains unknown.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue earlier today. I fixed it by changing the font size from 0.0 to 17.0. I hope this helps.